# PhoneGap – prevent screen lock

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am doing some investigation in to developing an app that will target Android/iOS/Windows Phone mainly.

I will probably use PhoneGap Build.

I can not get an answer regarding the following:
Can I prevent the screen locking when my application is running?

This will be critical as the app will track GPS data for up to 3 hours potentially.

If I use plugins, will this prevent me using PhoneGap Build?
I would prefer not to have to set up different environments to target the different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need continuous tracking or do you really need the app to be visible, all the time?

Have you tried this setting (iOS only), for instance: **exit-on-suspend**
Your app will continue to run while being in background, if you set this flag in the **config.xml**.

```
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
```

[PhoneGap Documentation: Configuring Remote Builds](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_pgb_config.md.html#Configuring%20Remote%20Builds_ios_preferences)

Comment: it looks like this is only the case of iOS

Comment: You are right, the docs list this setting as iOS only. Thx, I will edit my post.
PhoneGap Build Docs:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_pgb_config.md.html#Configuring%20Remote%20Builds_ios_preferences

Comment: I just want the screen to stay open and not time out like normal